# Can I take limsup and liminf on both sides of the inequality?

Tags: real-analysis

I have $g(n)<f(n)$ but I only know that $g(n)$ converges as $n\to \infty$. The problem is that I don't know if the limit of $f(n)$ exists, so instead of proving that one, I want to take liminf on both sides to get $\lim_{n\to\infty}g(n)\leq \liminf_{n\to\infty}f(n)$. Would there be any leap of logical step in my argument? I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: You can take $\lim \inf$ on both sides and replace it by limit on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an increasing sequence of integers $a_n$ (in particular, $a_n\to+\infty$) such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(a_n) = \liminf_{n\to\infty} f(n)$.
Since $g( a_n ) \leq f( a_n )$ for all $n$
we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} g(a_n) \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} f( a_n )$,
i.e., $\lim_{n\to\infty} g \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} f$.